# C# Regexes: Named and numbered capturing groups

Tags: c#, regex

Given

```
var re = new Regex(@"(?<name>\w+)(x)\1\2");
Console.WriteLine(re.IsMatch("yxxy"));
```

Prints `True`, it appears unnamed capturing groups are numbered starting with `1`, and *then* named capturing groups are assigned numbers afterwords. Is this correct/intended behaviour?

Comment: Seems like a weird behaviour. Never tried what you've done above but I always thought it started from the left hand side with the numbering.

Comment: @mastoj: Yeah.... I thought it might too...which is why I had to investigate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least MSDN says so. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(VS.71).aspx. In the newer version of this article it is confirmed, but it's more difficult to find this info. [Named matched subexpressions are numbered consecutively from left to right after matched subexpressions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx)

Comment: @Mark: You should be careful with this if moving to other programming languages’ regexes. It’s more common for the numbered groups to be strictly left-to-right, whether they also have a name or not.